# What should I install for rails 5.1 - font-awesome-sass, font-awesome-rails or font-awesome-less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, font-awesome, icon-fonts

When installing font awesome in a new rails application, I never can't seem to remember which one to use. Theres

```
https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-less
```

When in doubt, I ask myself, what would the rails author use. So what would the rails author use?

Answer (score 1):

I've used `font-awesome-rails` since my first project (from Rails [book](https://www.manning.com/books/rails-4-in-action)) and It worked very well.
This gem is also active, you can look at [the releases](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/releases).

I think the others can work well although I've never used it. "Front-end Gem" is just a bundle as an asset for the Rails asset pipeline (some gems have helpers) and It help you not have to download them manually from the homepage then put them to the proper directories.

In my opinion, the most active gem, the better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the 'new' Font Awesome 5 svg icons check out this gem 
which exposes a view helper called `faw_icon` https://github.com/alexwebgr/faw_icon and it provides three ways to load svg into your application

1. using the icons.json from the metadata
2. using the raw single svg files
3. using the svg sprites

by design it doesn't bundle any icons catering for a small download size and giving the developers the ability to update the icon sets as new ones become available, use custom ones or the PRO collection